# Can somebody add a tag for compute-module-4 please

Tags: support

Could somebody add a tag for **compute-module-4** please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

To add a new tag on the main site, you need 300 rep:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags

The paragraph under **How do I create a new tag?** explains the details.

With regard to the model specific tags, however, keep in mind that you will be doing yourself and others a favour by using the *most general tag* applicable. Eg., if you have question about compute modules that isn't really specific to a given model, use [compute-module](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compute-module)  instead of [compute-module-n](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compute-module-n).  You could also use both, if you think part of the question is general enough.

Comment: Thanks I just added it..